# Find circle center point that is tangential to line segment and another circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Given circle A (center point and radius $R$ is given), and a line segment (2 points are given: $P_{0}$ and $P_{1}$).

$P_{0}$ is on the circle.

There is another circle with given radius $r$, and it is tangential on the circle and the line segment.

What is the circle's location? (there are 2 possible locations)

[image]

Comment: Is $P_1$ inside of the big circle?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: *There are 2 possible locations*. With your schema, it is indeed true. But if if the segment $(P_0,P_1)$ has a second intersection with the circle or if $P_1$ comes *close enough*, you will get 2 additional locations...

Comment: And if $r>R$, I think that no location is possible. Said differently, what exactly are the condition on the given $R, r, P_0$ and $P_1$ besides *$P_0$ is on the circle (with radius $R$)*?

Comment: I think it is also possible to have exactly three locations.

Comment: After thinking again to it, the number of solutions can be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, depending on the position of P1, R and r. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I'm going to accept the diagram as providing the de minimus context for this Question, but as @SergeBallesta comments, some clarification of the problem's setup and goal is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_1=(x_1,y_1),\space P_0=(x_0,\sqrt{R^2-x_0^2})$; the center should be in the circle $x^2+y^2=(R-r)^2$

By geometry of the figure, the  center $C$ can be found as follows:

$(1)$ Ligne $P_1P_0:ax+by=c$ where $a,b,c$ are known. So there are two  distant parallel of $r$ from the $P_1P_0$ whose equations are
$$ax+by=c\pm r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$(2)$   The center is given by the system
$$\begin{cases}ax+by=c\pm r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\x^2+y^2=(R-r)^2\end{cases}$$
EXAMPLE.- $(R,r)=(5,1),\space P_0=(3,4), P_1=(-2,1)$ and line $P_0P_1:\space 3x-5y=-11$

Parallel lignes to a distance $r:3x-5y=-11\pm\sqrt{34}$

Solutions of the two systems $(x,y)=(0.889,3.9)$ and $(x,y)=(2.889,2.767)$ So we get the two circles
$$(x-0.889)^2+(y-3.9)^2=1 \text { and } (x-2.889)^2+(y-2.767)^2=1$$ which appear in the attached figure.

[image]